# Allow egress traffic to single IP address

Tags: kubernetes, configuration, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I'm writing the network policies of a Kubernetes cluster. How can I specify a single IP address that I want to authorize in my egress policy instead of authorizing a whole range of IP addresses ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An example based on the [official docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#the-networkpolicy-resource):

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: test-network-policy
  namespace: default
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      role: db
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  egress:
  - to:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 10.11.12.13/32
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5978
```

It's essential to use `/32` subnet prefix length which indicates that you're limiting the scope of the rule just to this one IP address.

Comment: @ Bernard : will this allow egress calls from same IP (10.11.12.13) but from different port lets say 443 ? or egress calls will only be allowed from 10.11.12.13 IP and 5978 Port ?

Comment: @solveit the IP/port pair in the rule above designates a destination for the egress traffic. So, if you want to change the rule to match the destination port, just change the `.spec.egress.ports.port` field.
On the other hand, if you're looking how to limit ingress traffic (from IP to the cluster), you need to use the `.spec.ingress` rules instead of the `.spec.egress` that's used in this example. Both have a similar logic and syntax though.

Comment: Fine example, thanks! Note though it will lead to a new problem (a minor and easily corrected one): failure in name resolution. Need to allow DNS traffic as well.